# Creating a custom event for script completion

Tags: javascript

I load some JavaScript dynamically by appending it to the DOM.

At the end of the JavaScript I want to create a custom event alerting the rest of the code that script has completed.

Here is what I have:

```
Su.throwEvent = function(){
    var load_complete = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    load_complete.initEvent( "focus", true, false );
    document.getElementById( 'ue_email' ).dispatchEvent( load_complete );
};
```

this does not work because I tied it `ue_email` which is a user input...so now every time the user focuses on the inputs it fires the event.

What is the correct way to create a custom "hidden" event.

I am looking here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind it to a hidden input control's `onchange` event.

That should work just fine, and is certainly simple, but hijacking the DOM's event system seems like a bit of a hack to me.  I'd create a global array of event listener functions, and call those from within the loaded script:

```
if (window.loadedListeners) {
    loadedListeners.forEach(function(listener) {
        listener();
    });
}
```

Remember that when you use `Array.forEach()` if you want to support IE7 and IE8, you need to extend Array manually to include that method.  You can use [the implementation at developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility).

Comment: There are many ways.  But I guess you are saying create a hidden element and use this.  This is best practice I take it?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - No, I wouldn't say it is a best practice.  But, it's close to what you've already got, and eliminates the possibility of user interference.  I updated my answer with an alternative that I would use.